# Why do structured and unstructured discretizations give different errors?

Tags: linear-algebra, matlab, finite-element

It is necessary for me to solve a Poisson problem with a numerical method on a square domain with two types of triangular mesh: uniform triangular mesh (using uniform distribution nodes on square) and nonuniform triangular mesh using pdetool in MATLAB.

The first one leads to a banded matrix and the second one leads to a sparse matrix but not banded. This is the only different between two method. It should be noted that the sparsity of two matrices are the same. Also the condition numbers of those are nearlly equal.

But the result by using uniform triangular mesh is much better than the second one.
Is there anyone who know about this problem?

Also, I should say the quality of two meshes are same.

[image]

Comment: Does the non-uniform mesh have any particularly *thin* elements?  What metric are you using to evaluate the quality of the meshes?

Comment: Not really, in the uniform mesh, the mesh quality of each element is 0.86 using pdetriq MATLAB command, so the avarege is 0.86. but for non-uniform the min qulity is 0.7 for a few triangles but the average is about 0.9.

Comment: Also, what metric are you using to evaluate the "size" of the finite elements in each mesh?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know how to add a picture, but I produce them by the following in MATLAB

Comment: x=[0 1 1 0];y=[0 0 1 1];
d=[3;4;x';y'];
do=decsg(d);
[p,e,t]=initmesh(do);

t=t';
t=t(:,1:3);
figure
trimesh(t,p(1,:),p(2,:));
[x,y]=meshgrid(0:1/14:1, 0:1/14:1);

x=x';
y=y';

x=x(:);
y=y(:);

t=delaunay(x,y);
figure 
trimesh(t,x,y);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21231/discussion-between-paul-and-rosa).

Comment: Assuming at least one of linear solvers used is iterative (banded solver could be exact), are the convergence tolerances the same for both solvers?

Comment: Sorry, but I  can't undrestand your statement.I use \ in MATLAB for solving their systems. So I think everything is the same.

Comment: Could you provide a convergence plot? Refine the mesh for both cases and plot on a log scale the decay of error. This might give a better idea of how the two methods are performing respectively. Error analysis for most numerical PDE methods are asymptotic results, therefore it is not really possible or meaningful to evaluate them based on a single error calculation - you must perform many for varying mesh size.

Comment: Also be sure you are giving relative error and not absolute error. Divide by the norm of the solution in all cases.

Comment: How do you compute the errors? Do you really compute the L2 error of the exact vs the discrete solution or of the discrete solution to an interpolant? In the latter case there exist superconvergence and supercloseness results on structured meshes.

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with banded/non-banded matrices: since you use the `\` operator to solve your system, you will always obtain an exact solution to your discretized problem (up to roundoff effects). The question is therefore how well the solution of the discrete problem approximates the exact solution.

I assume that you use a standard FEM with Courant elements (piecewise linear and continuous). We know, by Céa's Lemma, that the discrete solution will be quasi-optimal in the sense that it is only by a constant factor worse than the best possible approximation of the solution that your discretization space allows.

So what you really have to ask is how good the approximation properties of your discretization space are. The typical approximation properties derived for the FEM usually assume that the mesh is quasi-uniform and shape-regular. In other words, the elements are roughly the same size and none of them are extremely stretched in one dimension. If this assumption is violated, then we must expect a degradation of the approximation quality.

I recommend you to read up on these topics in any standard textbook or lecture notes on numerical methods for elliptic PDEs. Please ask if you need pointers on particular sources.

A practical concern is also if the two discretizations you use have the same or at least comparable number of degrees of freedom.

Comment: I don't think you should say that the backslash is exact up to roundoff.  Certainly, the errors in the solution of the linear system will almost always be much larger than roundoff (since most matrices are not perfectly conditioned).

Comment: @DavidKetcheson: You are right, of course. I should probably say "up to roundoff and conditioning effects". However, in my experience, I have never seen this error dominate the discretization error, and certainly not on such a simple, small FEM example.

Comment: You're still leaving out the amplification of error due to stability of the algorithm.  But I agree that for a small mesh and simple problem, the issue is almost certainly either a bug or the discretization.

Answer (score 3):

As underlined in other answers, there are errors due to the discretization, errors that come from the resolution and roundoff errors. Usually, the discretization errors dominate (at least on meshes that are not too fine).

Here is an example of structured mesh and unstructured mesh:

[image]

When the mesh has symmetry properties, like in the structured case, "superconvergence" phenomena may occur. Searching for articles containing this keyword (together with triangular meshes, finite elements) will give plenty of results like: https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/numerical-mathematics-theory-methods-and-applications/article/abs/mesh-quality-and-more-detailed-error-estimates-of-finite-element-method/D699D2462841058F48C5DFFEB2274752

When working on structured meshes, the symmetry of the triangle patches may cancel additional terms in the error estimate, leading to a higher order of convergence. For example on a triangular mesh, one would expect for P1, Lagrange finite elements to have $\|\nabla u -\nabla u_h\| = O(h)$, but on meshes with symmetries a faster convergence of the type $\|\nabla u -\nabla u_h\| = O(h^2)$ is observed.

Answer (score 2):

There are two sources of error, and each of them will be different for your two discretizations.

1. **Truncation error**, also referred to as discretization error.  This results from the fact that you approximate the Laplacian by a discrete stencil.  This error will remain even if you solve the linear system exactly; the only way to reduce it is to use a finer or more accurate discretization.  Since you haven't specified precisely the discretization you are using in each case, it is impossible to say by how much the discretization errors differ.
2. **Error in the linear solver**.  Since you are computing in finite precision arithmetic, you will not obtain an exact solution to the linear algebraic system given by your discretization.  As you are aware, the influence of roundoff errors will be amplified by the conditioning of the problem, and also by the stability of the algorithm you use.  MATLAB's backslash operator uses a variety of algorithms, depending on the structure of the matrix in question.  It is possible that it is able to use an algorithm with better stability for the banded matrix, thus leading to a smaller error (even though the matrices have similar condition numbers).

It seems most likely that the difference you see is due to #1, but #2 cannot be ruled out based on what you have written.  Also, it may be helpful to consider a third possibility: that there is a bug in the unstructured grid code (which is necessarily more complicated than the structured-grid code).  It would be useful to quantify what you mean by "much better".  If both solutions appear to converge to the same thing upon refinement, a bug is less likely.